# Sourcemaps not working in React Native Debugger

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-cli

Im having problems when trying to debug React Native in the react native debugger standalone app on a Mac. The project is started via the packager and run in the Android Simulator.

I cant access any sourcemaps, only the bundled code. The thing is that it works perfeclty when running the code and packager against my iOS emulator and XCode, but when starting a debug session from Android Studio and bundling with the packager I can run my solution just fine, but I cant access any sourcemaps.

I have no idea how to get passed this... How can I troubleshoot the packager and its sourcemap handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by going into settings for React Native Debugger and clicking "Restore defaults and reload" now I can see the sourcemaps again for both platforms!

Answer (score -1):

The settings and the button can be found here
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).